# Python Class Import Error

Tags: python, class, import

I'm studying classes and OO in python and I found a problem when I try import a class from a package. The project structure and the classes are described below:

```
ex1/
    __init__.py
    app/
        __init__.py
        App1.py
    pojo/
        __init__.py
        Fone.py
```

The classes:

Fone.py

```
class Fone(object):

    def __init__(self,volume):
        self.change_volume(volume)

    def get_volume(self):
        return self.__volume

    def change_volume(self,volume):
        if volume >100:
            self.__volume = 100
        elif volume <0:
            self.__volume = 0
        else:
            self.__volume = volume

volume = property(get_volume,change_volume)
```

App1.py

```
from ex1.pojo import Fone

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fone = Fone(70)
    print fone.volume

    fone.change_volume(110)
    print fone.get_volume()

    fone.change_volume(-12)
    print fone.get_volume()

    fone.volume = -90
    print fone.volume

    fone.change_volume(fone.get_volume() **2)
    print fone.get_volume()
```

When I try use **from ex1.pojo import Fone**, the following Error is raised:

```
fone = Fone(70)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

But when I use **from ex1.pojo.Fone import ***, the program runs fine.

Why I can't import the Fone class with the way I've coded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python you can import the module or members of that module

when you do:

`from ex1.pojo import Fone`

you are importning your module `Fone` so you can use

`fone = Fone.Fone(6)`

or any other members of that module.

But you can also only import certain members of that module like

`from ex1.pojo.Fone import Fone`

I think it is worth reviewing some of the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) on python modules, packages, and imports

Comment: hmm, strange. I thought that the import of modules was equal to the import of classes in terms of syntax. This confused me because I'm used to construct classes in Java, but  Python treats .py files as modules.Because of this, the module name has been capitalized

Comment: @AndréCaldas yes in python your module can contain multiple classes, or a multiple functions or a mix

Answer (score 3):

You should import class, not module. Example:

```
from ex1.pojo.Fone import Fone
```

Also you should lowercase naming convention for your module names.

Comment: I'm used to construct classes in Java,so I thought the name of the module should come capitalized, like Java. but I enjoyed your tip about convention!

Answer (score 0):

```
from ex1.pojo.Fone import Fone
```